# Why are these two matrixes not concatenating properly

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix, mean

I have two matrices:
`theoretical_mean` and `sampleMean`

I'm trying to merge both of them into `theor_sample_mean`, with the first value of `theoretical_mean` separated by a hyphen with the first value of `sampleMean`. Here's my code:

```
sampleMean <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sampleMean),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sampleMean <- round(sampleMean,digits = 3)
sampleMean

sampleVar <-lapply(lyst, var)

sampleVar <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sampleVar),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sampleVar <- round(sampleVar,digits = 3)
sampleVar

theor_sample_mean <- matrix(paste(theoretical_mean, sampleMean, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames = dimnames(theoretical_var))
theor_sample_var <- matrix(paste(theoretical_var, sampleVar, sep=" - "),nrow=7,dimnames= dimnames(theoretical_var))
theor_sample_mean

Thank you very much.
```

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example

Comment: here, output was too long but this link here. https://imgur.com/a/ySlJPtP.   first image is what im getting, 2nd image is what id like it to look like. it keeps repeating that first block 7 times

Comment: hope that helps to explain it

Comment: with images, i cannot test it.  You can use `dput`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use ```dput```

Comment: @akrun don't know if this will help, but I checked and noticed that ```sampleMean``` is actually a data frame

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look up the manual page for `dput` and figure out how to use it. Here's some made up data. Don't convert things to data frames if you don't need to.

```
set.seed(42)
samMean <- matrix(sample.int(100, 16), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)
samVar <- matrix(sample.int(100, 16), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE)
matrix(paste(samMean, "-", samVar), 4, 4)
#      [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]     
# [1,] "49 - 36" "65 - 95"  "25 - 5"  "74 - 84"
# [2,] "18 - 34" "100 - 92" "47 - 3"  "24 - 58"
# [3,] "71 - 42" "89 - 24"  "37 - 30" "20 - 43"
# [4,] "26 - 15" "3 - 22"   "41 - 93" "27 - 8"
```

Run this code and print out `samMean` and `samVar` to see that the correct pairs are being combined.